# Xamarin Forms Geofence

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Hi I need Geofence Sample in Xamarin Forms. need any Sample please Share me. i  tried Different Samples but i did't get Exact Out Put. Some Samples getting dll exception. Please share me any one.

Comment: Can you clarify what you have tried or used? there's too little information to know what you want exactly

Comment: Hi , whether has a try with this sample (https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/Geofence) .By the way , if occurs error , you can share the error log here .